# .Net best approach SQL Server 2008 incremental update based on up to date version

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

Assuming daily certain up to date database is produced via loading from various sources. 
Changes need to be applied to historical database based on uid, new records will added , non existing will be softly deleted , some will be updated. Is Ado.Net and Sql statements the most appropriate technology for the task like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If you need to schedule such operations, you can use SQL server agent.